# Advice for best path to working with Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

For the last 10+ years I have been developing desktop software.  I have successfully avoided learning most Web technologies.  Specifically:

- ASP (any version)
- HTML5
- MVC
- MVVM

I do know a modicum of other Web technologies, like REST and SOAP services, Javascript, and altering a Web Config file.  I'd like to be able to move my career towards Web, especially these Amazon Web Services (AWS).  Having looked around, it seems that they are being developed by hardcore Web developers.

To be able to develop AWS, what is my shortest (or best) path through learning some of these other Web technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing software on Amazon Web Services is, in general, no different to developing software on other computers. You use the same operating systems, programming frameworks and networking standards.

The benefits of choosing to use a cloud vendor like AWS are:

- Easy access to resources on a **pay-as-you-go model** (eg use a virtual machine for a few hours, then turn it off and stop paying)
- The ability to **scale-out to add extra capacity** when needed, then scale-in to remove excess resources when they are not needed (thereby saving money)
- Taking advantage of **application services** such as a queueing service, notification service and database service rather than having to deploy and manage the yourself
- The ability to **script the deployment of resources** so they can be automated in an easily repeatable manner

**Cloud vendors take care of the boring activities** of deploying and managing systems so that you can concentrate on the more-interesting, **value-added activities** such as writing code and delivering business value.

**Bottom line:** It doesn't matter whether you use a cloud service like AWS. You'll be using the same technologies, but you'll be able to avoid the boring bits. As to which technologies you should learn, that question is too open-ended for a forum like StackOverflow, which is setup to answer specific questions around software development.